# Fill values of dataframe using series

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame `df1` :

```
Name         IDN
John Arnolt  NaN
John Arnolt  NaN
John Arnolt  NaN
Armin Zhu    NaN
Wanda Von    GE3214
Wanda Von    NaN
Wanda Von    GE3214
Jan Krasicky GE432
John Arnolt  GE211
```

And I have series `s2` :

```
Name             
Armin Zhu    GE00
Wanda Von    GE3214
Wanda Von    GE3214
Jan Krasicky GE432
John Arnolt  GE211
```

How can I fill the NaN values in `IDN` df1 with corresponding values from s2?

I tried `combine_first` :

`df1["IDN"].combine_first(s2)`

But its not working (seems jupyter is stuck infinite loop)

Comment: Is `Name` the index of `df1`?

Comment: No its a column

Comment: There may be more columns in df1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map`, but you need to remove duplicate values in `s2`:

```
df1['IDN'] = df1['IDN'].fillna(df1['Name'].map(s2[~s2.index.duplicated()]))
```

Output:

```
           Name     IDN
0   John Arnolt   GE211
1   John Arnolt   GE211
2   John Arnolt   GE211
3     Armin Zhu    GE00
4     Wanda Von  GE3214
5     Wanda Von  GE3214
6     Wanda Von  GE3214
7  Jan Krasicky   GE432
8   John Arnolt   GE211
```

Comment: I think you can use fillna directly without map `df1.set_index("Name")["IDN"].fillna(s2[~s2.index.duplicated()])`, it will allign on in the indices.

Comment: @Erfan Certainly but there are some notes: 1) that changes the data structure; 2) it creates an on-the-fly copy of `df1` which can be huge; 3) one needs to be careful when assign the new column, e.g. passing the values.